# AWS API Gateway vs AWS Cognito

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cognito

I'd like to run some stateless Java services on the Bitnami stack on AWS that will be consumed by apps... and of course to access these I'd need some type of authentication and authorization.

Previously with this type of architecture I've chucked an API gateway in front of them, to which the developer would subscribe. And AWS provides an ***API gateway***, nice.

*HOWEVER*, while reading up on how to set this up on AWS I came across ***'AWS Cognito'***  which is supposedly designed specifically for this same purpose.

So my question is ***are these two solutions comparable - are they doing the same thing?***

***And if-so, then what are the pros and cons of each, when would choose one over the other?***

Answer (score 2):

Basically because you are targeting the user level you should use Cognito; as it does provide you with authentication, reseting passwords for the user, and of course 
signing up workflow. Moreover it provides user information to the admin, as well as two factor authentication, by using the user's mobile phone.
If you want to authorize the application to use an api then you use the API Gateaway.

The Cognito, is designed for user interaction it has an api for Java, JavaScript, iOS, and Android, so you can 
implement the interaction with it at any level; as you wish. You also not getting changed if your user base is less than 50k.